# Bulk flag comments

Tags: script, comments, flags

### About

I often go through my previous questions on SO/SE and find a lot of them have long resolved discussions. Ideally, I should raise a post flag and say "all comments below are obsolete; please delete". However, quite often there are 20 comments, out of which - say - only comments 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, and 13 are obsolete. In such a case, I've to manually flag each of them as no longer needed.

This userscript helps to flag comments in bulk. Screenshot:

[image]

---

### **[Direct install link](https://github.com/GaurangTandon/BulkFlagCommentsSE/raw/master/BulkFlagComments.user.js)** and [view source](https://github.com/GaurangTandon/BulkFlagCommentsSE/blob/master/BulkFlagComments.user.js)

Last updated: 22nd Dec 2019

---

#### Licence

Do whatever you wish to do, just don't sell this for money (but may use it in a commercial software's code) or state that you made it yourself. Do post here an answer if you do something cool with this :D

---

#### Contribute

Post bugs or feature requests as answers below!

Comment: The script broke with the new UI change. Changing `post-menu` to `js-post-menu` seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

### This post will help you get an access token

Please first install the userscript via [this link](https://github.com/GaurangTandon/BulkFlagCommentsSE/raw/master/BulkFlagComments.user.js).

(this post will dynamically change based on your current state)

Comment: See my answer to your linked question.  This "answer" here is not needed at all, once you use the correct approach

Comment: @user202729 Thanks, it was due to a different reason and I've fixed it!

Comment: What happens when the user use this script to flag their own comment?

Comment: @user202729 The script detects that it's the user's own comment and deletes the comment instead.

Comment: (not sure if it's fixed in the newest version but) I just have to retract a bunch of flags because if you press [cflag] on 2 answer on 2 different pages, then press "select all" on one, the other will be selected too.