# Cannot get redirect_uri to work

Tags: support, api, authentication, oauth2

This is in regards to my userscript [Bulk flag comments](https://stackapps.com/q/7935). I am sure I have not at all updated the userscript [since the first release of June 24](https://github.com/GaurangTandon/BulkFlagCommentsSE/commits/master/BulkFlagComments.user.js), and I am sure I was able to register for an access token last month.

However, today, I can no longer get the `redirect_uri` to work. I get an error: `'stackapps.com/a/7936' is not a valid uri`. I pushed an update to set the `redirect_uri` to `https://stackapps.com/a/7936`. However, after that update it just redirects to the corresponding StackApps page without any accesstokens in the query parameters.

So, has the SE API changed recently? If it hasn't, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There have been no reported changes to the API, [officially for many years](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/change-log), ([unofficially since January](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=%5Bapi%5D%20API%20%5Bstatus-*%5D)).

But, frankly that script's approach should have never worked.  OAuth credentials are sent to:
    `https://stackapps.com/a/7936#access_token=y6rVASxxxxxxxxxRO2R9Bg))` (for example)

But this is immediately 302 redirected to:
    `https://stackapps.com/questions/7935/bulk-flag-comments/7936#7936`

So the current script cannot see the access token.  <sup><sub>(Except maybe on a really bad network/system, but one shouldn't count on such things.)</sub></sup>

Anyway, You should **never OAuth redirect to a page that is not fully owned and controlled by yourself, and on your server -- unless it is the officially provided URL for client side OAuth.**<sup>‡</sup>

[For the Stack Exchange API, this URL is](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication): `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/login_success`.

See [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293498/148310) on Meta Stack Exchange for [**framework code and an example of using authentication with a userscript**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/293498/148310).

---

<sup>‡</sup> Not only is that brittle (as you have discovered), it can also be a major security risk, depending on the page chosen.